# update in MSSQL of MySQL Database via Linked MySQL-Database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, linked-list

I'm using MSSQL Server 2008.
I'm trying to update a MySQL database. I joined the MSSQL-Database with the MySQL-Database and now trying to complete the update, but having a strange problem.

When I do the following Query, I get a limited amount of results:

```
select *
FROM [SQL-Database].[dbo].[Table] as c left join
openquery(MYSQL, 'select * from MySQL-Database.Table')
on c.KuNr=kunden_id collate German_PhoneBook_BIN
where c.Auswahltyp='2' and c.[gelöscht]=0 
                       and c.[Mietzeit bis]>GETDATE() and c.aktiveMail>'0'
```

When I do the update, it updates ALL rows in database:

```
update openquery(MYSQL, 'select * from MySQL-Database.Table')
set paket_id=7
FROM [SQL-Database].[dbo].[Table] as c left join
openquery(MYSQL, 'select * from MySQL-Database.Table')
on c.KuNr=kunden_id collate German_PhoneBook_BIN
where c.Auswahltyp='2' and c.[gelöscht]=0 
                       and c.[Mietzeit bis]>GETDATE() and c.aktiveMail>'0'
```

The difference is just Select and Update, but it's kind of ignoring the "where" in the update.

Comment: You would probably be better off using an SQL Server Linked DB and Table Synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

Alias your openquery and it should work, like:

```
update k
set paket_id=7
FROM [SQL-Database].[dbo].[Table] as c left join
openquery(MYSQL, 'select * from MySQL-Database.Table') as k
on c.KuNr=k.kunden_id collate German_PhoneBook_BIN
where c.Auswahltyp='2' and c.[gelöscht]=0 
and c.[Mietzeit bis]>GETDATE() and c.aktiveMail>'0'
```

Comment: Hi!

Thank you for your quick reply. I'm a big step further with your query now.

But still some difference :(

Instead of wrongly updating the whole table (~14.000 rows) it now updates 514 rows. But the select query shows 537 rows :-/


I now tried to update all rows (with query below). But it's just updating 1847 rows. Don't understand this. Could there be a misconfiguration in ODBC oder MSDASQL?

update d
set d.paket_id=0
FROM [SQL-Database].[dbo][Table] as c left join
openquery(MYSQL, 'select * from MySQL-Database.Table') d
on c.KuNr=d.kunden_id collate German_PhoneBook_BIN

Comment: Thank you. I'm just stupid ^^ I was so deep in getting the query to work and show the same results like the select, that I forgot, that the SQL-Table has some double occurring values. Just checked the double values and voilá matches the sum.